# Android Which is the best way to store URLs? Static data members or in String.xml?

Tags: android, url, static

I have a large number of urls (almost more than 30) in my application. I have placed them in a class as static data members. I want to ask is it better than storing in String.xml file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store them as string resource if the URL will not be changed. It is similar to `public static final`

Answer (score 1):

Storing them as string resources only gives an advantage if you have different URLs for different languages/locales. Otherwise there's no benefit.

Comment: Storing the url in strings makes modification more accessible, as it is now stored in xml rather than code.